# How can I disable func init() autocomplete in GoSublime?

Tags: go, sublimetext2, sublimetext3

Every time I enter the keyword `int` which is quite often.. I get a suggestion for autocompletion on

```
func init() {

}
```

So every time I write `int` and press enter I end up with this function, and then I have to manually remove it and then rewrite `int` again and click left and right arrow a couple of times until the autocompletion disappears.

This is a horrible experience when you have to do it so many times in 1 hour.. How can I solve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your GoSublime package settings (copy the default to user if you haven't already), there's a line that goes:

```
{"text": "init", "title": "func init()", "value": "func init() {\n\t$1\n}"},
```

Delete it and I think you'll be fine

Comment: Thanks Lebowski! You can keep your Johnson.

Comment: @Aiden mein name ist Karl Ich bin expert